# Finding interface of COM object

Tags: php, com

I was trying to use com_event_sink, I came across a problem

**Here is a example from php.net**

```
<?php
class IEEventSinker {
    var $terminated = false;
    function ProgressChange($progress, $progressmax) {
        echo "Download progress: $progress / $progressmax\n";
    }

    function DocumentComplete(&$dom, $url) {
      echo "Document $url complete\n";
    }

    function OnQuit() {
        echo "Quit!\n";
        $this->terminated = true;
    }
}
$ie = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
// note that you don't need the & for PHP 5!
$sink = new IEEventSinker();
com_event_sink($ie, $sink, "DWebBrowserEvents2");
$ie->Visible = true;
$ie->Navigate("http://www.example.org");
while(!$sink->terminated) {
com_message_pump(4000);
}
$ie = null;
?>
```

In the line

```
com_event_sink($ie, $sink, "DWebBrowserEvents2");
```

I know the interface used to perform event sink is "DWebBrowserEvents2".

My question is,
Is there anyway that I can view the interface of a COM object?
Since I only got an OCX file with no documentation, I have no idea how to find the interface. Thanks

Comment: If you are lucky, the OCX may have a type library built into it. You can inspect it with OleView tool (comes with Visual Studio; not sure if it's available standalone anywhere). The type library would describe all the interfaces the server exposes.